# SharePoint Import Migration API

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-migration, migrationapi

I’ve been looking at the following [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/migration-api-overview)for the SharePoint Online Import API.

Under Best Practices and Special Mentions - Package Size they have a paragraph around number of items.

Is a package a job or a manifest file. For example if I have 1000 folders these would go into Manifest.xml (250 items), manifest1 (250 items) , manifest2 (250 items) and then manifest3 (250 items)

If any one could clarify or point me on the right direction it would be much appreciated. Thanks